# What scopes/roles are required to add to use platform alerts API using ConnectedApp in Anypoint Platform

Tags: mulesoft, anypoint-platform

I have provided the Manage Alerts and Read Alerts scopes to connectedApp to access platform apis. When trying to create alert using ConnectedApp credentials in platform APIs throwing an 403 error (Access Issue).

If I had given scope OrgAdmin and tested. It works fine

I don't want provide OrgAdmin to connectedApp . What are scopes do I need to add to create alert using platform APIs using connectedApp credentials

Comment: To what alerts exactly are you referring on Anypoint Platform? There are Runtime Manager alerts, API alerts, Monitoring alerts? What is the specific API that you are using?